# Objective C - TableViewController embedded in a ViewController - What triggers the table view to process the data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I'm building an iPad app that will have a table view in one sector of the window with other labels, images, buttons, etc elsewhere. I know how to create a tableView when using a tableViewController as the class of the scene, but can't figure out how to populate the table cells when the table view is embedded in a scene with a UIViewController class.

I have updated my .h file as follows:

`@interface SKMainViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>`

I'm returning data from an asynchronous API call into the viewController, but can't figure out how to initiate the required tableView methods (tableView:numberOfRowsAtIndexPath and tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath). How can I trigger them to run once I've got my data back? Is there a simple method call I don't know about?

I've dissected a functioning UITableViewController class and don't see what triggers the population of the table cells.

**EDITED:** Adding large sections of code for your review. I've trimmed out the other imports and property declarations to simplify.

This is SKMainViewController.h:

```
#import "SKWelcomeViewController.h"
#import "SKAgenda.h"
#import "SKAgendaManager.h"
#import "SKAgendaCommunicator.h"
#import "SKAgendaManagerDelegate.h"
#import "SKAgendaTableViewCell.h" // I'm using a custom cell

@interface SKMainViewController : UIViewController <SKFlipsideViewControllerDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate, NSURLConnectionDelegate, SKGreetingManagerDelegate, SKWeatherManagerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    NSArray *_agenda;
    SKAgendaManager *_aManager;
}

#pragma mark Agenda Detail
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *agendaItems;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *agendaTableView;

@end
```

This is SKMainViewController.m:

```
    #import "SKMainViewController.h"

    @interface SKMainViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation SKMainViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [self startFetchingAgenda:_agendaItems];
}
-(void)startFetchingAgenda:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSInteger deviceID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"deviceID"];

    if(deviceID == 0)
    {
        // todo: add error handling here
        NSLog(@"Bad stuff happened");
    }
    [_aManager fetchAgendaForDeviceID:deviceID];
}

-(void)didReceiveAgenda:(NSArray *)agendaItems
{
    NSLog(@"Received these agenda items: %@", agendaItems);
    _agendaItems = agendaItems;
    if(agendaItems.count == 0)
    {
        // set defaults to populate a single cell
        NSLog(@"No Items!");
    }
    else
    {
        // populate data and present
        NSLog(@"Some Items!");
        agendaTableView.delegate = self; // Error Here: use of undeclared identifier 'agendaTableView'
        agendaTableView.dataSource = self; // Error Here: use of undeclared identifier 'agendaTableView'
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [_agendaItems count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.agendaSpinner startAnimating];
    self.agendaSpinner.hidden = NO;

    static NSString *tableIdentifier = @"agendaTableCell";

    SKAgendaTableViewCell *cell = (SKAgendaTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"agendaTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    // set the data related to the agenda item
    SKAgenda *agendaDetails = [_agendaItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.agendaTitle.text = agendaDetails.title;
    cell.agendaDescription.text = agendaDetails.description;
    NSString *eventTimes = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", agendaDetails.start, agendaDetails.end];
    cell.agendaTimes.text = eventTimes;

    //todo: add functionality for background and text colors. Will need to use RGB colors instead of HEX. Change in webiste.

    // todo: accommodate for no events in the agenda

    [self.agendaSpinner stopAnimating];
    self.agendaSpinner.hidden = YES;

    return cell;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you paste your code here. Easier to understand you. And from what you're saying setting the delegate to self will do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the data source and delegate:

```
myTableView.delegate = self;
myTableView.dataSource = self;
```

Where `self` is your `SKMainViewController` that adopts the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols.

If at any time you'd like to reload your table data:

```
[myTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense...and it's simple like I figured it would be. However, it's not working. I've defined myTableView to be agendaTableView. When I enter what you suggest only substituting my tableView name, I get errors for each line. The error is "Use of undeclared identifier 'agendaTableView'; did you mean '_agendaTableView'. If I take the suggestion from xCode or use 'self.agendaTableView' the error goes away but it still doesn't call the code related to populating table cells (and I'm sure I have data to display). I'll edit the original question with some more code. Thanks.

Comment: @SteveSTL You need to reload your data using `[myTableView reloadData]`. I meant myTableView to be whatever reference you have declared to your table view, which should be `_agendaTableView`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the simple method is reloadData. This causes the table view to call its data source methods. You need to put it in a completion block (or delegate that's called after the data is received) if you're using an asynchronous api.